# error defining std::function pointer to an instance of a function template, which is a member of a templated class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm getting the following error trying to declare an std::function pointing to a templated class member.

> Error  C2672   '`std::invoke`': no matching overloaded function found

```
template <typename InputArchive, typename OutputArchive, typename ... Components>
class LevelSerializer {
...
    template <typename Component>
    void initRegistry() {
        ...
        std::function<void(entityx::Entity, OutputArchive)> f(std::bind(&LevelSerializer<InputArchive, OutputArchive, Components...>::saveComponent<Component>, this)); // errors
    }

    ...
    // I'm trying to point to an instance of this function
    template <typename T>
    void saveComponent(entityx::Entity& entity, OutputArchive& archive)
};
```

`entityx::Entity` is a fixed (non-template) type. Why does doing this fail?

Comment: Just don't use bind at all, use a lambda instead. This is considered best practice in modern c++.

Comment: @Nir Friedman I've tried this, but I cannot pass a lambda as a non-const reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems:  Firstly, your line:

```
   std::function<void(entityx::Entity, OutputArchive)> 
       f(std::bind(&LevelSerializer<InputArchive, OutputArchive, Components...>::saveComponent<Component>, this)); // errors
```

should be

```
   typedef std::function<void(entityx::Entity, OutputArchive) functype;
   typedef LevelSerializer<InputArchive, OutputArchive, Components...> LS;

   functype f(std::bind(&LS::saveComponent<Component>, this, 
                                          std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 ));
```

Your problem is that as you have written it, your call to std::bind is trying to return a a function with no arguments (and it ends up not having enough arguments for the member function you are trying to call).  You need to bind in the place holder arguments so that a) the member function has enough arguments; b) the result is a thing that has two arguments.

As an aside: Inside the LevelSerializer template, a naked `LevelSerializer` refers to the template with its arguments.  So actually, you just need:

```
   typedef std::function<void(entityx::Entity, OutputArchive) functype;

   functype f(std::bind(&LevelSerializer::saveComponent<Component>, this, 
                                          std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 ));
```

Your second problem is that the signatures don't match (thanks to Piotr Skotnicki for this).  The template argument to `function` is for a function that takes two parameters *by value*.  Your member function takes two arguments *by non-const reference*.  You need to change at least the template argument to:

```
   typedef std::function<void(entityx::Entity&, OutputArchive&) functype;

   functype f(std::bind(&LevelSerializer::saveComponent<Component>, this, 
                                          std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 ));
```

... but you might want to change the `entity` argument to be by const reference.

Comment: One more thing to note is that the defined `std::function` takes arguments by value, while `saveComponent` expects modifiable lvalue references. Unless you change the signature of the `std::function`, it won't compile, since `std::function` forwards the arguments which in this case means "turns into xvalues"

Comment: Good spot!  I have update the answer to correct this.

Comment: Thanks for spotting both issues. If we're already telling std::function the function signature, why is it still necessary to use placeholders to forward the arguments?Shouldn't that be something determinable at compile-time?

Comment: Also, I unfortunately only saw the part about the mismatch between the std::function template arguments and the arguments for the actual function after spending a while tracking down the source of some mysterious crashes. The mismatch unfortunately still compiles with no warnings in MSVC 2015.

Comment: Because that's the way the language works.  Maybe you have a member function that takes (int,int), but you want to bind it with placeholder::_2, placeholder::_1.  Also, you may not want to make the free arguments be the last two (they could be the second and the fourth).  Finally there is a lot of levels of template meta-progamming going on here; being explicit gives the compiler a better chance to issue comprehensible error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Martin Bonner addressed the question more directly, but I thought I'd note that in my case I received this error for the following code:

```
std::bind(&ClassName::FuncName, objName, _1);
```

And fixed it like so:

```
std::bind(&ClassName::FuncName, objName, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Apparently one of my headers included a boost library with placeholders, and _1 was pointing to the boost version instead of my version.